# Undefined black color is showing in the react js project

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am making one project in React JS using custom CSS and also deployed in the Amazon S3. In the project I have made two circles using the overlay and border radius but in some phone like Redmi 6 and Redmi 6A the circle is being shown in the black color. I have tried so many ways, please help me and let me know the solution for the same.

I am sharing the code and image:

Image:
[image]

HTML Code:

```
<div id="sign1"></div>
<div id="sign2"></div>
<div id="sign3"></div>
<div id="sign4"></div>
<div id="sign5"></div>
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Css Code:

```
#circle {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 148px;
    border: 17px solid white;
    margin-top: -18.7%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  #circleNew {
    width: 103px;
    height: 103px;
    border: 23.8px solid #fff;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    margin-top: -39%;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  #circle1 {
    margin-top: -39%;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  #sign1 {
    margin-top: -44.8%;
    margin-left: -36.6%;
  }
  #sign2 {
    margin-top: -12%;
    margin-left: -18.5%;
  }
  #sign3 {
    margin-top: -4.5%;
    margin-left: 77px;
  }
  #sign4 {
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 32.5%;
  }
  #sign5 {
    margin-top: 3.2%;
    margin-left: 41%;
  }
```

Comment: Did you tried remote debugging in chrome? this might help to get into the excat problem https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

Comment: You are using webkit specific property ` -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` and `mix-blend-mode`  which is not supported in `Edge` or `IE` . So that might cause problems considering the fact that probably those phones ( and others ) do not use a webkit browser.

Comment: I am using the chrome browser and I have used the ` -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;`. But I still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: CSS without HTML is useless, please add your HTML to the question.

Comment: I have updated the question, please have a look.